# Create histograms in Grafana with alphabetical values as x-axis

Tags: postgresql, histogram, kibana, dashboard, grafana

I need to create a dashboard to be used in a control room, where a bunch of operators will need to monitor the number of tasks assigned to other employees (among other aspects).

Source data will be coming from a RDBMs (PostgreSQL, in this case). We have *people* with *assigned and numbered tasks* that also have a *status*, and the DB data is like this (purely fictional: but it resembles the real one)

[image: Example of data]

Having to create and mantain a dashboard i was thinking to use tools like Grafana, Kibana or similars, to plot something like this

[image]

The problem is that Grafana, for example, **doesn't let me use alphabetical values for the x-axis**. It only allow numeric values, while i've names to plot (Mark, Luke, Brian).

Is there a best practice than i can follow? Am i trying to use the wrong tools?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually solution is easier then you think although it also took me some time to figure it out. I will place here an example for some unspecified shop data grouped over countries - you just need to change it for your task. Example was tested on Grafana 5.0.3

1. PostgreSQL query for metrics

> ```
> SELECT
>   $__time( partition_date ),
>   country as metric,
>   sum(value) as value
> FROM
>   aggregations.my_data_for_dashboard
> WHERE
>   shop = 'myshopname' AND 
>   $__timeFilter(partition_date )
> group by 1, 2
> ```

Grafana will show usual metrics:
[image]

2. In "Axes" tab look at "X-Axis" section, item "Mode" - switch "Time" to "Series" and Grafana will show bar chart for countries.

[image]